# Firebase RealTime-Database for Users

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Heloo guys! I'm creating an app and I want that every user to save his information and it will be stored in my firebase realtime database.I watched a lots of tutorials but nothing worked.I created something simple.A button which gives the command to store the data,2 EditText for first name and second name.My problem is that nothing in database is written.I want that every logged in user to store his information separately. The firebase authentication is done.I created a UserDetails class that have  get and set for first name and second name.I only intialized the button and the EditText because I deleted the commands for realtime database because it didn't work and my app crashed when I opened the UserDetails activity.

I

UserDetails(activity class)

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class UserDetails extends AppCompatActivity {
    private FirebaseAuth auth;
  private DatabaseReference reference;
  private FirebaseDatabase database;
  private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener authStateListener;
    private FirebaseUser user;
    private EditText firstName;
    private EditText secondName;
    private Button saveInfo;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate ( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView ( R.layout.activity_user_details );
        firstName=(EditText)findViewById ( R.id.firstname );
        secondName=(EditText)findViewById ( R.id.secondname );
        saveInfo=(Button)findViewById ( R.id.data );
        auth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance ();







    }

}
```

User(for get and set)

```
package com.example.myapplication;

public class User {
   public String firstName;
    public String secondName;
    public String uid;
    public String email;
    public User(){

    }



    public User (String firstName, String secondName, String uid, String email) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.secondName = secondName;
        this.uid=uid;
        this.email=email;
    }

    public User (String firstname, String secondname) {
    }

    public String getFirstName () {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getSecondName () {
        return secondName;
    }

    public String getUid () {
        return uid;
    }

    public String getEmail () {
        return email;
    }

    public void setFirstName (String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public void setSecondName (String secondName) {
        this.secondName = secondName;
    }

    public void setUid (String uid) {
        this.uid = uid;
    }

    public void setEmail (String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

Rules for realtime database

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    "$user_id":{
       ".read": "auth.uid === $user_id",
       ".write": "auth.uid === $user_id"

    }
  }
}
```

Data in realtime database

```
sports-buddy-eb866
users
firstname: 
true
secondname: 
true
```

I want to store every information below the userID  after the user is logged in  but nothing is written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

refer to inputs from my side,

1. Park the security rules, make it public for now, once you are able to put data from Android, then you can work on rules.
2. Firebase real-time database stores data in JSON tree.
3. The following instruction will get you a reference to particular {userId}. If it's not available i.e 1st time, it will automatically create an entry.

`DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users/{userId}");`

4. you can set user object or hashmap to ref `ref.setValue(hashmap)` or `ref.setValue(user)` (HashMap will contain key-value pair or user will be an instance of your User class)

additional links:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write

Hope this helps, happy coding!

Comment: Can you be more explicit please? I used the additional link that you gave me but didn't work.I'm new on firebase.I don't know what to do exactly.I tried everything I found but nothing is written in the database.

Comment: Please make sure that you have removed the rules for testing. Also, can you please check the log for any information that can help us pin point the problem?